# Am i using the wrong code for different iPhone sizes

Tags: ios, iphone

The following is the height and width of iPhone 6 divided by 2.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    if(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==667.0f) &&([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width==375.0f)) {

    }}
```

If i need a platform to fall at bottom of screen and regenerated back on top of screen i type in code...

```
 platform.center.y >667
 platform.center=CGPointMake(ONE.center.x, -10);
```

However, the farthest the platform falls is 600 and then it regenerates back at top. Am I not using the correct code for the different iPhone size?

Comment: I recommend using autolayout. that way you don't have to put all these hard coded height values

Comment: I was done with app on Xcode 5.1.1 but when i just downloaded code 6.1 for some weird reason auto layout makes the UIImageViews glitch horribly with auto layout. When i turned it off the glitch disappeared. Don't know how to fix that glitch. So i'll work without auto layout.

Comment: Sounds very familiar :) I went through exact same issue. Even auto layout is really confusing and frustrating in the beginning but it gets better as you go along. Good Luck!